# python - Append dataframe but remove null column from each table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have two dataframes in python:

**df1**

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 123 | RJ | 12.1 | test1 |
| 2a | 432 | MT | 23.2 | test3 |
| 3a | 234 | DR | 34.3 | test5 |

**df2**

| Column1 | Column3 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | RJ | 695 |
| 2a | MT | 568 |
| 3a | DR | 232 |

**And I wish to append them together and save them as CSV, separated by pipe.**

But when I simply append, there are lots of columns with nulls:

```py
df3 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 123 | RJ | 12.1 | test1 |  |
| 2a | 432 | MT | 23.2 | test3 |  |
| 3a | 234 | DR | 34.3 | test5 |  |
| 1a |  | RJ |  |  | 695 |
| 2a |  | MT |  |  | 568 |
| 3a |  | DR |  |  | 232 |

**Then when write into CSV give me this result:**

```py
df3.to_csv('df3.csv', sep='|', index=False) #I will also remove header ',header=False'
```

Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5|Column6|

1a| 123|RJ| 12.1| test1||

2a| 432|MT| 23.2| test3||

3a|234|DR| 34.3|test5||

1a| |RJ|| |695|

2a| |MT|| |568|

3a| |DR|| |232 |

**But what I need as results is this output, ignoring nulls (don't worry about header):**

Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5|Column6|

1a|123|RJ|12.1|test1

2a|432|MT|23.2|test3

3a|234|DR|34.3|test5

1a|RJ|695

2a|MT|568

3a|DR|232

**Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.**

I've tried this code below but still got 'NaN'

```py
pipe_delim_rows = df3.apply(lambda x: '|'.join([str(v) for v in x.values if v not in (np.nan, '', None)]), axis=1)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in pipe_delim_rows:
        f.write(item + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you just want df1 on top of df2.

If that's the case, just write them both out to the same file. No need to create a third DataFrame if you don't care about headers or column spacing.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': {0: '1a', 1: '2a', 2: '3a'},
                    'Column2': {0: 123, 1: 432, 2: 234},
                    'Column3': {0: 'RJ', 1: 'MT', 2: 'DR'},
                    'Column4': {0: 12.1, 1: 23.2, 2: 34.3},
                    'Column5': {0: 'test1', 1: 'test3', 2: 'test5'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': {0: '1a', 1: '2a', 2: '3a'},
                    'Column3': {0: 'RJ', 1: 'MT', 2: 'DR'},
                    'Column6': {0: 695, 1: 568, 2: 232}})

with open('file.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    df1.to_csv(f, sep='|', index=False, header=False)
    df2.to_csv(f, sep='|', index=False, header=False)
```

File.txt

```
1a|123|RJ|12.1|test1
2a|432|MT|23.2|test3
3a|234|DR|34.3|test5
1a|RJ|695
2a|MT|568
3a|DR|232
```